# If the user reacts with , I want the bot to edit the message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Something like this.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    a = await client.say("React to see help")
    if reaction.emoji == "":
        await client.edit_message(a, "Moderator commands")
```

Here's an example: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/562005351353024525/569931890577113098/unknown.png
But I want the bot to edit the first message. Can someone help?

Comment: please edit your question so we understand that you are using discord.py to create a discord bot. Also, provide a working example of code

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a message when the bot comes online, then monitor that message for new reactions.  The easiest way to do that is with a background loop using [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), instead of the `on_reaction_add` event.  The `reaction_check` function is to make finding the right reactions easier.

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
from discord import Client

grin = "\N{GRINNING FACE}"

def make_sequence(seq):
    if seq is None:
        return ()
    if isinstance(seq, Sequence) and not isinstance(seq, str):
        return seq
    else:
        return (seq,)

def reaction_check(message=None, emoji=None, author=None, ignore_bot=True):
    message = make_sequence(message)
    message = tuple(m.id for m in message)
    emoji = make_sequence(emoji)
    author = make_sequence(author)
    def check(reaction, user):
        if ignore_bot and user.bot:
            return False
        if message and reaction.message.id not in message:
            return False
        if emoji and reaction.emoji not in emoji:
            return False
        if author and user not in author:
            return False
        return True
    return check

client = Client()

async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(int(*SOME CHANNEL ID*))
    msg = await channel.send("React to see help")
    await msg.add_reaction(grin)
    while not client.is_closed:
        res = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=reaction_check(message=msg, emoji=grin))
        if res:  # not None
            await msg.edit(content="Moderator commands")

client.loop.create_task(background_loop())
client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the package [`discord_interactive_help`](https://github.com/astariul/discord_interactive_help), which allow you to display a bunch of pages and let your user interact with this manual **through reactions**.

*Disclaimer : I am the author of `discord_interactive_help`.*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to detect the reaction with your current code, your problem would be your edit.

```
channel = a.channel
msg_id = a.id

if reaction.emoji == "":
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
    await msg.edit(content = content)
```