# Trying to check if a wait_for reaction is a certain emoji

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to check if one of my wait_for returns, is a certain emoji.

I've tried str(one.reaction.emoji), I've tried one.reaction.emoji

```
charm = discord.Embed(description=f"React With The Corresponding Emoji, What You Wish To Edit.", color=0xff89ff)
charm.set_author(name=f"{user.name}")
charm.set_thumbnail(url=str(user.avatar_url))
charm.add_field(name="Name", value=":one:")
charm.add_field(name="Sexual Preference", value=":two:")
charm.add_field(name="Biography", value=":three:")
charm.add_field(name="Hobbies", value=":four:")
charm.add_field(name="Location", value=":five:")
editmsg = await user.send(embed=charm)
await editmsg.add_reaction(emoji="1\N{combining enclosing keycap}")
await editmsg.add_reaction(emoji="2\N{combining enclosing keycap}")
await editmsg.add_reaction(emoji="3\N{combining enclosing keycap}")
await editmsg.add_reaction(emoji="4\N{combining enclosing keycap}")
await editmsg.add_reaction(emoji="5\N{combining enclosing keycap}")
one = bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=onecheck)

if str(one.reaction.emoji) == "1\N{combining enclosing keycap}":
await user.send("What Do You Wish To Change Your Name To?")
```

Comment: Could you share the definition of your `onecheck` function?

Comment: ```def onecheck(reaction, user, m):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "1\N{combining enclosing keycap}" and isinstance(m.channel, discord.abc.PrivateChannel) and m.author.id == user.id```

Comment: The check will only receive `reaction` and `user`. [Here is some code I wrote for generating checks for reactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55798859/6779307)

Comment: so would i use your check to check if the returned emoji is the one i want, if so how? @PatrickHaugh

Comment: pass `check=reaction_check(message=editmsg, emoji=[f"{i}\N{combining enclosing keycap}" for i in range(1,6)], author=user)`.  `emoji` can be a unicode emoji or an `Emoji` object, or a sequence.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh but i also wish to check which emoji they used, not just if they used the emoji too, so if they used the one emoji, it would print "1" and if it was the two emoji, it would print "2"

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30.0)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await user.send('I did not receive your reaction :(')
else:
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        await user.send('Haha')
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        await user.send('Say something')
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        await user.send('and so on')
    ...
```

Comment: `reaction` is going to be a [`discord.Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction) object, so it will never be equal to a string.

Comment: if i do `if str(reaction) == "emote":` it might work

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks for your observation!! I just edited my answer