# How do I react to a message when it's edited

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been looking for an answer for a while and haven't found anything, I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807384/discord-py-help-command-react-to-edit-message) and saw the answer, I tried it, but it didn't work, I tried some other stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798114/if-the-user-reacts-with-i-want-the-bot-to-edit-the-message) as well, but they're all either out of date or in python rewrite. I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: There’s no such thing as python rewrite, I think you’re talking about discord.py rewrite, also that’s discord.py version +1.0.0, so I’m pretty sure it’s the right version as the older versions aren’t supported anymore

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the `on_raw_message_edit` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_message_edit(payload):
    message = payload.cached_message

    if not message:
        channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    await message.add_reaction("")
```

In the code, we're first checking if a cached message exists, as to not make an unnecessary API call. If it does exist, then we use that message instance.

If it doesn't exist in the bot's cache, then we get the channel, and using the channel instance, we can fetch the message.

---

**References:**

- [`on_raw_message_edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_message_edit) - This will trigger for messages that aren't in the cache as well as cached messages.
- [`discord.RawMessageUpdateEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawMessageUpdateEvent) - The payload passed to the triggered event.
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
- [`Messageable.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)
- [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction)